# requireNativeComponent was not found in UIManager

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, kotlin

I know this question has been asked many times but all the questions refers to integrating a third party dependency in `react-native` app but in my case it is because of my own native code and I am having issues on how to fix it. I am using `react-native` 0.69.

Here is snippet of my code. In CealScanQrViewManager.kt:

```
class CealScanQrViewManager(
    private val reactContext: ReactApplicationContext
) : ViewGroupManager<FrameLayout>() {
    private val cealScanQrView = "CealScanQrView"

    // ...

    override fun getName() = cealScanQrView

    // ...
}
```

On the JS side, I have created a CealScanQrViewManager.tsx file:

```
import {requireNativeComponent} from 'react-native';

export const CealScanQrViewManager = requireNativeComponent(
  'CealScanQrViewManager',
);
```

In App.tsx:

```
const App = () => {
  // ...

  const [isCameraPermissionGranted, setIsCameraPermissionGranted] =
    useState(false);

  // ...

  useEffect(() => {
    requestCameraPermission();
  }, []);

  // ...

  const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
        {
          title: 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
          message:
            'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
            'so you can take awesome pictures.',
          buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
        },
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        setIsCameraPermissionGranted(true);
      } else {
        console.log('Camera permission denied');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  };

  // ...

  return (
    <SafeAreaView /* ... */>
      {/* ... */}
      {isCameraPermissionGranted ? (
        <CealScanQrViewManager
          /* ... */
        />
      ) : (
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

As soon as I grant the camera permission I get error saying:

> requireNativeComponent CealScanQrViewManager was not found in UIManager

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official guide to native components](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.69/native-components-android) has you register a view manager, which is a class that overrides `getName` to return a fixed string, and then pass that same string to `requireNativeComponent`.

In your code, those names do not match.  You [`requireNativeComponent('CealScanQrViewManager')`](https://github.com/PritishSawant/AndroidCameraXWithFragment/blob/bceabc40c0cdf5849684a40315faf3e9dc61afc2/CealScanQrView/CealScanQrViewManager.tsx#L3-L5), but [register it as `"CealScanQrView"`](https://github.com/PritishSawant/AndroidCameraXWithFragment/blob/bceabc40c0cdf5849684a40315faf3e9dc61afc2/android/app/src/main/java/com/myapp/ceal_scanqr_view/CealScanQrViewManager.kt#L18,L32).  As the official guide explains,

> Name returned by `getName` is used to reference the native view type from JavaScript.

If the name does not match, no wonder looking up the type fails.

Comment: Can't believe I made such a stupid mistake